# dompdf positioning errors

Tags: php, dompdf, pdf-conversion

This may have been asked multiple times, but is there a good HTML-to-PDF creator for PHP?

I'm currently using [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/), and there is a whole list of unsupported things (such as `postion:absolute` inside a `position:relative` container, and `float:right`) which make my PDF render incorrectly.

dompdf forces me to make tables in order to align stuff the way I want.  I made an HTML page using floats and relative+absolute positioning, but dompdf ignores this and overlaps all my text and positions them wrong.

It also randomly put a blank 2nd page even though I have both `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` set to avoid.

So, can anyone tell me a good PHP PDF creator, or tell me a workaround for dompdf's lack of floats or relative+absolute positioning (I *hate* tables)?

P.S. I am using dompdf 0.6.0beta1

Comment: Although you do not state it explicitly, you mean HTML -> PDF conversion within PHP, as opposed to regular PDF creation.

Comment: @Orbling: Yeah, that's want I meant.

Comment: Take a look at mPDF - http://mpdf.bpm1.com/ which I've recently discovered... no guarantees (I'm working with HTML tables anyway rather than styles for positioning) but it looks like it generates a good, clean PDF from HTML

Comment: @Rocket: HTML rendering is incredibly complicated on a screen, rendering to print seems more complicated still, judging by the way most of the major browsers handle it.  Always consult the [compatibility list](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility) when using `dompdf` for HTML.  I do not know any *better* HTML to PDF converter in PHP.

Comment: @Mark: I tried mPDF, it seems to be better than dompdf.  It doesn't support relative+absolute positioning, but it doesn't overlap text.  Unfortunately, other HTML files (using tables) don't look right in mPDF.  Oh well, guess I can just go and fix those to look correct.

Comment: The final 0.6.0 release will have some significant improvements in positioning support. Have you taken a look at the latest code? [The examples](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/docs_0-6-0/examples.php) include a "position_all" document that uses a variety of positioning methods. Unfortunately, float support is still underdeveloped, so I don't know if it'll be ready for the next release.

Comment: @BrianS: It's nice to see that they are updating it.  I just re-did, my HTML with tables, and it's ok for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to re-write my HTML using tables, so dompdf will render it the way I want.  mPDF looked nice, I may switch to that in the future.